# Prevent MobileFirst Platform from presenting adapter response in Native iOS App

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Overtime I request something from an Adapter of MobileFirst Platform 7, I see the response on the log window on a Native iOS App.
This is consuming memory, blocking the execution of the App and annoying me :)

Is there any way yo block this ? If I want to see the response, I can use NSLog.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the ability to **not display** responses does not exists.
Feel free to submit feature requests, though...

Besides, is it really the *display* of the data and not the fact that you return probably *a lot* of data, thus it takes it longer to arrive before it finally gets printed?

Comment: The response comes quite quickly and, even after all data has been saved, the debug console still takes very long time to end the display of data